# Linear PRAM vs Arithmetic Linear PRAM

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, dc.parallel-comp

*A linear PRAM model* is a PRAM model without bit operations and at least one operand of the $\times$ instruction is a constant. If in addition we require that the running time does not depend on the bit length of the input then the resulting model is called the *arithmetic linear PRAM model*.

This 1999 paper ([ps file](http://ramakrishnadas.cs.uchicago.edu/lower-bound.ps)) of Ketan Mulmuley says "we do not know a natural example that is in the linear PRAM model but not in the arithmetic linear PRAM model". I am wondering if such an example is found in the last decade. Are there any potential candidates ?